# How to make an infinite loop say a raw JSON message once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently making an adventure map and I have an infinite loop that when I wear a helmet named "Helm of Knowledge", it'll empty my helmet slot, replace my ninth hotbar slot with the helmet and display some commands/hints for my map.

The loop however will always spam the text no matter what I try. I've thought of maybe making it test for a block at a certain location that is set by wearing the helm. I have no clue on how to do this though. Something like;

Wear helm, set redstone block at X Y Z (activating the tellraw sequence), remove helm, remove block, place helm back in ninth hotbar slot. I'm very bad at these type of commands so any help would be appreciated. Would this kind of thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a System that triggers once everytime the helmet is on the head.
[Here is a brief rundown of how this would be achieved](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/5f4bu0/repeating_testfor_cmd_impulse_cmd/dahf4tu/). You just need to adapt it to your system.
If you want to run it only once ever, you can remove the last two command chain commands.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler solution. Look at the image below:

[image: simpler solution]

I thought of a simpler contraption of what your confused Of. Radius AND powering it only once. The Repeating Command block is where you will put the radius. Like `/testfor @p[r=1]` Which means If You Step ontop of the command block. It will power the comparator. then in runs itno the block of your choice. Then powers the repeater. And Powers the command block at the bottom that has the Tellraw command. For Example I Used:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"Hello","color":"green","default":true}.
```

the comand block on the right however. Has a setblock command. You write down the coordinates of the repeater I suggest LOOKING DOWN to it. When you got it, You Do This:

```
/setblock {coordinates} minecraft:air
```

when you power the repeating command block. It Will power the tellraw, then it will get rid of the repeater. then it dosen't power anymore. You Put repeaters on the way to the setblock command so that the tellraw command will power first. I hope You understand! :)